# json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 5 (char 4) AND raise JSONDecodeError("Extra data", s, end)

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I'm working on a stock market analysis app using the yahoo finance api on rapidapi. I successfully pull the data from the api using requests and the result is a requests.model.response. I found that when I convert this to a json dict I get the following error (same as title):

json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 5 (char 4)/raise JSONDecodeError("Extra data", s, end)

to resolve the issue I tried alternatively converting the model.response to a string then back to a dict with the following:

responset = response.text
responseld = json.loads(json.dumps(responset))

I did this based off of some research I did online. No, it doesn't exactly make sense to me because this does merely seem to be a conversion of type then back to the same type. But I've thought that maybe dumps does something more than just a type conversion because I saw in another thread that this approach (that I've shown here) has been used to resolve a similar error for somebody else.

Do you have any advice? Please let me know if you need more information. Thank you.

Comment: Can you provide text of response that was failing with conversion?

Comment: Also one possible solution is to parse binary data of response directly using `result = json.loads(response.content.decode('utf-8'))`.  Here `response.content` is raw-bytes data of response.

Comment: Thank you for the responses and possible solution, I will try it out tomorrow. Are you looking for the full text of the requests.model.response? Or something else? I should be able to get that and post it tomorrow.

Comment: Basically to investigate your error (if my solution is not enough) would be nice to have both response data or url (if it is not secret) and piece of code that you use to convert this data to json. So that we can reproduce error on our side and try to fix it.

Comment: Also there is a built-in way to decode json response in requests which is `result = response.json()`. My code mentioned earlier above is more low-level and may be easier debugged.

Comment: That was the way that I decoded the json  response. As for your solution, it worked. Thank you very much.

Comment: I have a new error that arises, but I was able to work through many more stocks with your content.decode solution. Should I post that issue here because it's related or should I post a new question?

Comment: I think you can post your new related errors here, and I'll extend my answer. In order to figure out what is the problem please save failing `response.content` to binary file, i.e. do `with open('content.bin', 'wb') as f: f.write(response.content)` and post this file here.

Comment: BTW, also a good practice is to check response status like this `assert response.status_code == 200` because `requests` library doesn't throw any error on bad status. And when status is not 200 you may almost for sure expect HTML page (describing failure reason) in response instead of json.

Comment: If you're getting not 200 status code then it means there was server failure, and content has no json inside, for example URL is bad, or not existing then status will be 404. Only when status is 200 then you can be sure that there was no error, if not 200 then there was some error.

Comment: There also exists a short way to check status code by adding a line `response.raise_for_status()` it will throw error with description on bad status and do nothing on good.

Comment: The solution was working but has since stopped. I don't recall changing anything.
Here's the error text:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pullAppleb.py", line 92, in <module>
    responseJ = json.loads(response.content.decode('utf-8'))
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\json\__init__.py", line 357, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Program

Comment: What errors is it giving now? One common reason of stopping downloads from one server is due to server banning lots of requests from one IP. Just add line `response.raise_for_status()` to check server status and if there is no error but json is not parsed then write binary response to file and post file here, write to file using `with open('response.dat', 'wb') as f: f.write(response.content)`.

Comment: Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\json\decoder.py", line 340, in decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Extra data", s, end)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 5 (char 4)

Seems like basically the same thing as before but now it's happening with your fix in place and the error is occurring much earlier in the stocks. At an earlier stock that is than previously. Before I could make it through thousands without an error, now not even 100.

Comment: I've added response.raise_for_status() after m creation of the response now. Thank you.

Comment: I got a message stating: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pullAppleb.py", line 92, in <module>
    response.raise_for_status()
  File "C:\Users\Benjamin\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 941, in raise_for_status
    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 503 Server Error: Service Unavailable for url:

Comment: https://apidojo-yahoo-finance-v1.p.rapidapi.com/stock/v2/get-historical-data?frequency=1d&filter=history&period1=-252460800&period2=1599436800&symbol=AAON

If its an IP issue, why do they allow any requests at all? I should also mention that I'm a subscriber and have not reached my cap. Would there still be an IP issue?

Comment: For follow up I got a 503 - Service Unavailable error in the .dat file

Comment: Service Unavailable seems to be like IP blocking issue, they may have some per-hour quota for each IP. If you're paid customer of their service and this kind of queries are allowed by them then you may send this error code to their help service and they will clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to decode json from response obtained through `requests` library.

I expect that you got `response` with code similar to this:

```
response = requests.get(url)
```

First, most low-level, but reliable and easy to debug, it uses `response.content` which is raw body bytes of response:

```
result = json.loads(response.content.decode('utf-8'))
```

second uses `response.text` which is basically `response.content` automatically converted to text string using best matching encoding by `requests` library:

```
result = json.loads(response.text)
```

and most high-level and simple, where `requests` takes all care to do the right job of conversion:

```
result = response.json()
```

One of this methods should work.

Also after receiving response you always need to check status code, because `requests` doesn't throw exception on non-200 status code, so you need to do `assert response.status_code == 200` or `response.raise_for_status()` before decoding. Status code not equal to 200 always means that server responded with error and response will not contain json. Here is [List of HTTP Status Codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes).

All most common features of `requests` library (including json parsing) are described in short documentation [here](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/).